# Using manifest property in html5

Tags: html, manifest

From what I userstand,

```
<html manifest="test.appcache" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

that is a sample on how one would use the manifest property.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
# Offline cache v2
# html files
index.html

# css files
styles.css

# js files
main.js
```

and the above is a sample of the manifest file.

However, when I try to run it from my iTouch, the cache is not working.

I just want to ask if the server affects if certain html5 property work? because the server I am using is quite old.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the server delivers the manifest file with a MIME type of

```
text/cache-manifest
```

This could be done (assuming you're using apache) by adding

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

to your .htaccess file in the directory the manifest is residing in.